# Oryx CycloneTCP WebSocket Support for HTTP Server

Tags: websocket, tcp, stm32, stm32h743

I've started to evaluate `Oryx Embedded CycloneTCP` library, and able to run HTTP server / DHCP client with CubeMX config tools and `STM32CubeIDE` for custom `STM32H7` board.

However, I did not get how to configure `WebSocket` support for `HTTP Server`. So I need some help / sample / demo code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Its an a bit older question, but nonetheless...

https://gricad-gitlab.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/Projets-INFO4/20-21/05/STM32F7_CycloneServer

shows how to implement a simple websocket->CAN Bus gateway.

Take a look at `CycloneServer/Core/Src/main.c`

In `httpServerRequestCallback()` the http connection gets upgraded to a websocket connection.

Received frames are processed in a seperate task (`clientTask()`).

`sendCANBusToClient()` shows how to send messages to connected websockets.